# Click RadioButton and Perform Task

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get the following logic to work.

```
function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

filename = 'C:\Users\r001\Desktop\excel_files\Book1.xlsx';
A = xlsread(filename);

A = xlsread('C:\Users\r001\Desktop\excel_files\Book1.xlsx','Sheet1','A1:B10');

h = msgbox('Operation Is Completed');
```

When I click radiobutton1, no data is imported from the Excel file, but the message pops up saying the 'Operation Is completed'.

What am I missing here?

Also, and ideally, I'd love to use a Case statement for this.  I'd like to do something like:

```
function
   switch
      case1
      case2
      case3
   end
end
```

Comment: You need to [store the data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html).

Comment: I looked at the site; still not getting it.

function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton1
A = xlsread('C:\Users\r001\Desktop\excel_files\Book1.xlsx','Sheet1','A1:B10');
h = msgbox('Operation Is Completed');

get(A,'Value')
get(h,'Value')

set(A,h);

Now, I have this error:
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: edit your question and add that part, maybe someone can help